# Ati Radeon Xpress 1100/1150 Driver? Which one and how to install? Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

```
h@h:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS482/RS485 [Radeon Xpress 1100/1150] [1002:5974]
```

Thats my Graphics card. And all I need is a stable driver for this. Im running ubuntu 14.04, I tried installing fglrx but it didn't work I could not log in to ubuntu anymore.

I need to run 2 displays that are both 24", side by side so I can get larger workspace and run windows on vmware on other screen and main os, ubuntu on other. I hate windows but i need it too much to throw it away.

I just need someone to tell me how to install good graphics card. It can be fglrx but how do I avoid the login bug in that?

```
h@h:~$ dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core
```

ii  xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic                          2:1.16.0-1ubuntu1.2~trusty2                         amd64        Xorg X server - core server

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core` terminal command there.

Comment: And what is your "login bug"?

Comment: Login bug is that I cant log in normally. I had to delete fglrx with ctrl+alt+f1

Answer (score 0):

There is no proprietary standalone driver for this video adapter in linux.

Open source driver is already installed.

The only thing you can do is to upgrade graphical stack for the latest available version for Ubuntu 14.04. In your case you have it already.

You can upgrade to 3.19 kernel. It has a built in radeon module, which may be better. It can be done by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

New graphical stack must appear soon too in repositories.

Comment: I added it. How do I do that?

Comment: You have the latest possible graphical stack. But you can upgrade kernel with a newer `radeon` driver. I will add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works faster now. But I still cant get my displays side by side. I get this error when I try to do it: Requested size (3840, 1080) exceeds 3D hardware limit (2048, 2048).
You must either rearrange the displays so that they fit within a (2048, 2048) square.   You know how to bypass this error?

Comment: This old adapter may not have enough RAM to support two big displays. Or other hardware limitations.